# Append json data to django table automatically

Tags: python, html, json, django

I receive json files to my django website  when some asyncronous tasks are finished with celery.

I want to append json data automatically when it is available (without refreshing the page).

Any Ideas??

Thanks,

I tried to parse the json to the table directly but it doesn´t work.

```
        <table id="myTable" style="width:90%;font-style: normal;">
            <thead>
            <tr style="font-style: italic;">
                <th><div class="th-inner"> Proc. Started </div></th>
                <th><div class="th-inner"> Proc. Finished </div></th>
                <th><div class="th-inner">Result </div></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>

        {% for document in images %}
            <tr>

                <td>{{ document.image.date_image_upload }}</td>
                <td>    </td>
                <td id=jsonResultDiv> <h3 style="color: #FFFFFF;">Results will appear here...</h3>   </td>

                 <script type="text/javascript">

                    var DEV_URL = "{{ document.remote_processed_json }}";
                    var resultJsonUrl = DEV_URL;

                    function loadJSON(callback) {

                        var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
                        xobj.open('GET', DEV_URL, true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
                        xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                                // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
                                callback(xobj.responseText);
                            }
                        };
                        xobj.send(null);
                    }

                    loadJSON(function (response) {
                        // Parse JSON string into object
                        actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
                        var element = document.getElementById("jsonResultDiv");
                        element.innerHTML = "<h3>screening result:<h3>";
                        if (actual_JSON[0]['evaluation'] == 0)
                            element.innerHTML += '<h3 style="color: #66FF66;">Healthy.</h3>';
                        else if (actual_JSON[0]['evaluation'] == 1)
                            element.innerHTML += '<h3 style="color: #FF6666;">' + actual_JSON[0]['annotations'].length + ' micro found.</h3>';
                        else element.innerHTML += '<h3 style="color: #FFF000;">Problem parsing results file.</h3>';
                    });
                </script>
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: you should try something for that.If you get stuck somewhere come here and ask with your code..

Answer (score 0):

Would something simple like HTML autorefreshing the page every 30 sec or so work with your already-installed solution?  If so, see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp :

```
Refresh document every 30 seconds:
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
```

Comment: The author said that `without refreshing the page`, so it may not meet his or her demand.

Comment: that's more like a workaround than a solution, as it's not at all user-friendly

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for this:

1) You may use Django channels, where technically you will push new updates using `websockets`. You can find more info about it here: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

2) The second option is to make your frontend make `ajax` requests with a time interval, like 5seconds for example. This would call an API endpoint and with the data you're gonna get from there, you update your frontend.

Hope that helped - if you need more info I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I´ve tried to use Ajax to parse the json to the table (See my edited answer), but it doesn´t work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What's the problem with that, did you get stuck anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think here you should use addition work on javascript using ajax to get the latest data and change the page.
Once the template has been rendered and returned, it can't be changed easily.